# How to uninstall Windows Live Mesh?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-live-mesh

I'm on Windows 7, and can't seem to find Live Mesh in neither "Programs and Features", nor "Turn Windows features on or off".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows Live programs don't appear separately in the Programs and Features list. Instead, they're all under the entry **Windows Live Essentials**. Find that, click "Uninstall/Change", and then you'll be able to uninstall individual Windows Live programs.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in Programs and Features, try a) installing CCleaner (which is very useful anyways) and seeing if it appears in the uninstall list there and b) trying to delete the folder from Program Files (possibly from Safe Mode if necessary) followed by using CCleaner to clean up the registry.

Also, see if it's under Installed Updates, it may have come in as an OS update.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in "Programs and Features".

Perhaps try installing it again, which should hopefully repair it, including adding it's entry back to Programs and Features so that you can uninstall it properly.